# Drawing static text in a rotating canvas

Tags: android, canvas

So i have this onDraw function

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    Paint paint = mPaint;

                    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                    int w = canvas.getWidth();
                    int h = canvas.getHeight();
                    int cx = w / 2;
                    int cy = h / 2;

                    canvas.translate(cx, cy);
                    if (mValues != null) {            
                        canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
                    }
                    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

                    Paint paint1 = new Paint(); 


                    paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
                    paint1.setTextSize(25); 
                    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint1); 

                }
```

And what it does it draws a arrow that is rotating and the text is also rotating near the arrow what I want is a static text somewhere under the arrow... or something like that.

Comment: I figured it out! you have to do a canvas.save(); before rotating the canvas and a canvas.restore(); before using the canvas to draw the text that will be static!

Answer (score 1):

Use `canvas.save();` and `canvas.restore();` something like:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    int w = canvas.getWidth();
    int h = canvas.getHeight();
    int cx = w / 2;
    int cy = h / 2;

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(cx, cy);
    if (mValues != null) {            
           canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvans.restore();

    Paint paint1 = new Paint(); 


    paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint1.setTextSize(25); 
    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint1); 

}
```

Hope that helps.